# how to implement the switch case in python..?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Check this below code:

```
var = input("enter a number between 1 and 12")
def switch_demo(var):
    switcher = {
                1: "Jan" 
                2: "Feb" 
                3: "March"
                4: "April" 
                5: "May" 
                6: "June" 
                7: "July" 
                8: "August" 
                9: "Sept" 
                10: "Oct" 
                11: "Nov" 
                12: "Dec"
    }
    print switcher.get(var,"Invalid Month")
```

I am getting Syntax Error at line 5
How can I solve the error?

Comment: You forgot the commas.

Answer (score 7):

### Fixing your Bugs

You need to add a comma at the end of each item:

```
 1: "Jan", 
 2: "Feb",
```

Working program:

```
def switch_demo(var):
    switcher = {
                1: "Jan", 
                2: "Feb", 
                3: "March",
                4: "April", 
                5: "May", 
                6: "June", 
                7: "July", 
                8: "August", 
                9: "Sept", 
                10: "Oct", 
                11: "Nov", 
                12: "Dec"
    }

    return switcher.get(var,"Invalid Month")

var = int(input("enter a number between 1 and 12"))
print(switch_demo(var))
```

### Simpler Solution

You should have a look at the  `calendar` module.
It already provides all months names:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.month_name[3]
'March'
```

Comment: Thank you **@Mike**

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Switch case is a very powerful control tool in programming as we can control to execute different blocks of code with it.
In python you can implement it by using dictionary method and for your code posted,

```
var = input("enter a number between 1 and 12")
def switch_demo(var):
    switcher = {
                1: "Jan",
                2: "Feb",
                3: "March",
                4: "April",
                5: "May",
                6: "June", 
                7: "July",
                8: "August", 
                9: "Sept",
                10: "Oct",
                11: "Nov",
                12: "Dec"
    }
    print switcher.get(var,"Invalid Month")
```

Comment: Please add code tags otherwise its hard to read.